# Improper Bayesian Prior

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I was reading TPE by Lehmann andCasella where I came through this example:
If $X\sim\text{Bin}(n,p)$ and we consider a $\text{beta}(a,b)$ prior for $p$. The Bayes estimator in this case is $\frac{x+a}{n+a+b}$. If $a=b=0$, this estimator is $x/n$, but the prior density in this case is improper. The posterior density is proper if $1\leq x \leq n-1$ with $x/n$ as the posterior mean. When $x=0$ or $x=n$ the posterior is no longer proper.

**However any estimator $\delta(x)$ that satisfies $\delta(0)=0$ and $\delta(n)=1$, the posterior expected loss is finite and minimized at $\delta(x)=x/n$.**

I cannot verify this last part.

Comment: Quick note: this improper prior is known as Haldane's prior after John Burdon Sanderson Haldane, a British-born geneticist and evolutionary biologist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The posterior using Haldane's improper prior is proportional to $\theta^{x-1}(1-\theta)^{n-x-1}$, and it is improper when we observe no successes ($x=0$) or only successes ($x=n$). When $x=1,\dots,n-1$, the posterior is proper and the Bayes estimator with quadratic loss (aka posterior expectation) is $\delta(x)=x/n$. Now, when $x=0$, the posterior expected loss is proportional to
$$
  \int_0^1 (a-\theta)^2 \theta^{0-1}(1-\theta)^{n-0-1}\,d\theta = 
$$
$$
a^2\int_0^1 \theta^{-1}(1-\theta)^{n-1}\,d\theta - 2 a\int_0^1 (1-\theta)^{n-1}\,d\theta + \int_0^1 \theta(1-\theta)^{n-1}\,d\theta \, ,
$$
which is finite (and therefore minimized) if and only if $a=0$ (consider the first term). Something similar happens when $x=n$ (check it out), leading to the definition of the generalized Bayes estimator $\delta(x)=x/n$, for $x=0,\dots,n$.